# How do I create a pull-down/up window in Android GUI?

Tags: android, user-interface, popup, window, pull

For Android GUI: I would like to create a window that I can pull up from the bottom of another window, kind of like the Notification bar or the tab in the bottom on Spotify for Android.

I want to be able to grab a small piece of the window and pull it up. Or just click it and it will "pop up". And afterwards be able to pull or click it so it returs to its original space.

Does anyone know a good way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html)

Comment: Is there any alternative for this? SlidingDrawer is now deprecated :/